# relationship between pointers and arrays

Tags: c

My question is both specific to an assignment I'm working on and conceptual about the relationship between pointers and arrays.  I'm writing a hash table in the form of an array of pointers to sorted lists.  I've created a struct to define a type for the hash table and the number of elements in the table is defined in a macro.  Since the size of the table is variable, the struct needs to contain a pointer to the table itself - a pointer to an array of pointers.  My problem revolves around the idea that a pointer to some data type is the same as the label for the first element of an array of that data type.

I have a data type `SortedList`.  As I understand things, `SortedList*` can be interpreted as either a pointer to a single SortedList or as a pointer to the first element of an array of `SortedList`'s.  Expanding on that, `SortedList**` can be an array of `SortedList` pointers and `SortedList***` can be a pointer to that array.  This is what I have in my hash table struct.  My first question is, is my understanding of this correct?

In the function that creates the hash table I have this:

```
SortedList** array;

if ((array = calloc(size,sizeof(SortedList*))) == NULL) {
    // error allocating memory
    printf("Memory Error\n");
    return NULL;
}

table->arrayPtr = &array;
```

So `array` is intended to be my array of `SortedList` pointers and `arrayPtr` is the `SortedList***` type in my hash table struct.  I'm using `calloc` because I think it will initialize all of my pointers to `NULL`.  Please let me know if I'm mistaken about that.  This all compiles with no errors so, as far as I know, so far
so good.

I have function that inserts data into the table that first checks to see if this pointer has not been used already by checking to see if it points to `NULL`, if not, it creates a `SortedList` for it to point to.

```
int i = index->hashFunc(word);
SortedList*** table = index->arrayPtr;

if (*(table +i) == NULL){
    return 0;
}
```

So it seems to me that dereferencing `(table +i)` ought to give me a SortedList** - the ith element in an array of SortedList pointers - which I can then check to see if it's set to `NULL`.  Unfortunately, the compiler disagrees.  I get this error:

> error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘struct SortedList’ and ‘void *’)

So somewhere along the line my reasoning about all this is wrong.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: [You really need to understand pointers for this](http://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_ksplice_pointer_challenge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to read up a little bit more on arrays and pointers in C because I don't think you completely grasp the concept. I could be wrong but I doubt you'd need a three level pointer to achieve what you're trying to do; I think you might be confusing yourself and thinking that if you want to point to an array's data you need to point to the actual array (&array), which is essentially a pointer itself. Drawing a picture can also really help to visualise what's going on in memory.

An array is merely a block of sequential data, where the variable's name in C (without any [ ], which would get an element from the array) **points to the first element in the array**. The two lines in the example below are equivalent (where *array* is obviously an array):

```
int *p_array;
p_array = array;     /* equivalent */
p_array = &array[0]; /* equivalent */
```

You could then use p_array **exactly** the same way as if you were to use *array*, ie.

```
p_array[3] == array[3]
```

The unnecessary thing that some people might do when they're learning is have a pointer to a pointer to an array (which I think is what you're doing):

```
int **p_p_array = &array;
```

And then to access the elements of *array* they would have to dereference the pointer and then use array notation to specify the element in the array:

```
*p_p_array[3] == array[3]
```

What we've actually done here is store the **memory address** of *array* (which itself is a pointer to the first element), which we then have to dereference to get to the first element, and then we move 3 positions forward to get to the fourth element (*array[3]*).

In the first example it's so much simpler and more logical, since we're storing a pointer to the first element in the array and having the pointer act in the same way as our initial *array* variable.

I recommend you draw out what you're trying to do on a piece of paper/whiteboard to see what you're doing wrong and it may then become obvious how to properly implement it the right way. My whiteboard is one of my best tools when I'm coding something.

Comment: The links by Keith and J.F. explain it a lot better than I can; it's important to be able to know that there's a difference between a pointer and an array.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I think I've finally got it working now.  I was using one * too many.